# How to select dropdown list value in a mail

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, sql, asp.net

here is my problem:

I want to send a mail but the mail's template doesn't take account the dropdown list selected value.

On the server'side:
On a page web, I have a textbox. The textbox's content is loaded from a database. In this database, I have a field where the template is stored. in the template, I have added this code:

```
<label> titre </titre>
 <select id='list1'>
  <option>rent1</option>
  <option>rent2</option>
  <option>rent3</option>
</select>
```

So I have a dropdown list.

on the client-side:

My dropdown list appears properly but if I select a value, then mail that I send doesn't select any value.
Should I do a PostBack for my dropdown list? How Could I take the value in the mail?

I don't have access to the aspnet server script.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing inside the tag  the attribute value, this attribute holds the value of each option. Per example `<option value="rent3ID">rent3</option>`.

When you do the `document.querySelector('#list1').value` gonna return you the attribute value of the option selected

Answer (score 0):

You need to have names and values for your inputs. Then to access the values just get the value of the `select` input

```js
function log(){
    console.log(document.getElementById("list1").value);
}
```

```html
<label> titre </titre>
 <select id="list1" name="list1" onchange="log()">
  <option value="rent1">rent1</option>
  <option value="rent2">rent2</option>
  <option value="rent3">rent3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can collect the value bur my mail always indicate the default value.

Answer (score 0):

in my mail, I can't get the selected value. there are only the default value

In my mail, I have Title: [rent1V] and not the selected value
Why the value appear with [V]

---

```
<script>
document.querySelector('#list1').value
</script>

<label> titre </titre>
 <select id="list1" name="list1" onchange="log()">
  <option value="rent1">rent1</option>
  <option value="rent2">rent2</option>
  <option value="rent3">rent3</option>
</select>
```